# Noticeable delay when changing an image dynamically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and experienced a problem while trying to make a mobile application.
When switching the image being displayed there is a noticeable delay, where nothing is shown, between the action and the new image appearing.
Adding `gaplessPlayback: true` to the Image widget does prevent the original image disappearing until the other is loaded but the delay remains.
I tried to [precache](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) both images but noticed no difference in load time. Is this delay to be expected or am I doing something wrong?

[Issue without gaplessPlayback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhIW7.gif)

```
class Wallpaper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  StateWallpaper createState() => StateWallpaper();
}

class StateWallpaper extends State<Wallpaper> {
  late AssetImage walPath;
  late AssetImage wal1;
  late AssetImage wal2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    wal1 = AssetImage('assets/wal_dark.jpg');
    wal2 = AssetImage('assets/wal_light.jpg');
    walPath = wal1; //Set default wallpaper
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    precacheImage(wal1, context);
    precacheImage(wal2, context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          if (walPath == wal2) {
            walPath = wal1;
          } else {
            walPath = wal2;
          }
        });
      }),
      Image(image: walPath, gaplessPlayback: true)
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big are your images (width/height in pixels, and file size)?
Perhaps they are too large, and they are being resized before being displayed?
Try with images that are close to the pixel width/height of the device and see if it is faster...
Also, is it a release build?

Comment: Thanks to your answer I've manage to find the problem. It wasn't due to the file size but the pixel width/height of the image. The images were probably being cropped before being rendered causing the delay. Is this something I should keep in mind for all devices? Will an image might render slower if it needs to be cropped?

Comment: I did ask about pixel size too, not just file size. Yes, it will render slower and take more memory than necessary... try to keep the images a similar pixel size to the devices on which your app will run